# How to compute $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-{x^2}/{2}}}{1+e^{-(ax+b)}}\,\mathrm dx $ when $b \ne 0$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

I'm trying to solve this expression when $b \ne 0$:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-{x^2}/{2}}}{1+e^{-(ax+b)}}\,\mathrm dx $$

Using the answers provided to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870009/help-solving-integration-int-infty-infty-textstandard-normal-time) we can solve $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-{x^2}/{2}}}{1+e^{-x}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac12$$

However, when we change the power of exponential term in the denominator to $-(ax+b)$ from $x$, the expression can not be solved using the same methods used in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870009/help-solving-integration-int-infty-infty-textstandard-normal-time). I tried solving by substituting $z=ax+b$ and it also did not work.

Comment: Approximation: if $\left| a\right|  <<1$ then: $\frac{e^b}{e^b+1}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk can you please explain how that happens?

Comment: put `a=0` and integrate.

Comment: Closed-form formula for: $a=1$ and $b=1$ is: $1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}$. Another one: $a=1$ and $b=-1$ is: $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thanks for the suggestion, but $a \ne 0$. $a$ and $b$ can be any value except for $0$.